# UISearchDisplayController Activity Indicator

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uianimation

I'm using a UISearchDisplayController to display some search results in a table view.  Every time the text field of the search bar changes, the activity indicator spinner next to "Loading..." resets its animation.  That is, if I query "a" in the search bar, the activity indicator begins its spinning animation.  When I then query "aa," the activity resets its animation to the beginning of its spinning.  This looks a little jarring when you are rapidly typing out a long string, because the spinner doesn't spin smoothly; instead, it keeps resetting to the beginning.  Does anyone know how to make the spinner continuously spin as the table view loads results from the data source?

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually calling [myActivityView startAnimating] each time the search field updates? If so, you can can just check isAnimating first, so you don't (re-)start the animation:

```
if ( ! [myActivityView isAnimating]) {
    [myActivityView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure the activity view is handled by the UISearchDisplayController.  I don't have a handle to the view.